# program running programs in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a Python beginner (using 2.7) and want to know if there is a way for a program that I have written to run other programs.

Basically, I want to build a program that evaluates other programs.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What type of evaluation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. One of the examples given there:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
```

That should be pretty much all you need